# ASP.NET Repeater/ListView using Array to call SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, listview, repeater

I am making a wishlist that saves listingIDs as id1,id2,id5 etc into SQL.

I am trying to use an Array to make a listingID = id1, listingID = id2... call to SQL so that it displays all listings on one page.

Can I use Repeater/ListView with the Array for this?

Sorry if this is not very clear, I am pretty new to this. I have done an hour or so worth of research but it is not working out for me.

Thank you for the consideration.

Comment: your question is not clear? you have got an array of object that you want to display on your page?

Comment: I want to use the Array for a SQL comparison. WHERE listingID = ArrayItem1, ArrayItem2... etc. So I can display all info from each comparison on the one page.

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off if you create a `Listing` class that has the information you want to display in a repeater/list view/grid view, like this:

```
public class Listing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // And whatever else you want to display to the user and that exists in the database
}
```

Now, you can build a `List<Listing>` to use as your data source for your data-bound ASP.NET controls (repeater, list view, grid view, etc.), like this:

```
var listOfListings = new List<Listing>();
listOfListings = GetListingsFromDatabase();

GridView.DataSource = listOfListings;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes can use

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = "s1,s2,s3";
        string[] StrArray = test.Split(',');

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rptTest.DataSource = StrArray;
            rptTest.DataBind();
        }
    }


    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTest"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
        listingID = <%# Container.DataItem %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: How can I use this to make the database comparisons? This is an example which I can get my head around which I very much appreciate. I thought it may be as easy as WHERE listingID=<%# Container.DataItem %> but then I got all sorts of errors.

Comment: instead of my StrArray you can use your array that you make from database

Comment: I have pulled the Array from the database and the above code prints it perfectly, however I am having issues getting the Repeater to link to the listingID=ArrayItem1, ArrayItem2 etc for the repeater to call that SQL command.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am not very clear. I want ItemTemplate to display results of "SELECT * FROM Listings WHERE listingID = <%# Container.DataItem %>"

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your array to datagridview like this

BTW your gridview will look like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValueToBind" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Make a class

```
public class ValuesToBind
{
    public string ValueToBind { get; set; }
}

List<ValuesToBind> lstToBind = (
    from ar in yourArray
    select new ValuesToBind
    {
        ValueToBind = ar
    }).ToList();
gView.DataSource = lstTobind;
gView.DataBind();
```